# angular translate uses the key not the value to represent text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm following the ng-book on localization part. This is all i've done:

1) installed via bower install angular-translate
2) loaded it in via the script tag in my html where the file is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
```

3) added the module

```
var app = angular.module('eva', ['ui.router','ngMaterial','ngMessages', 'controllers', 'factories', 'ngAnimate', '720kb.socialshare', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

4) made a separate config

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations({
        HEADLINE: 'EVA - eet plantaardig!',
        INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
    });
}]);
```

5) changed a piece of code to the following for testing (html file)

```
<md-button href="#/profile"  layout-fill>
                  {{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}
                </md-button>
```

6) now whenever i go run my site, where "Profile" used to be, like it should, now there should be "EVA - eet plantaardig!" right? Nope, it only shows "HEADLINE".

Any ideas guys? I'm following the book but it won't work, i must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From their website you need to set the language:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    HEADLINE: 'EVA - eet plantaardig!',
    INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
});
```

This can be seen in the docs: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter:translate

Comment: Didn't work :s it's still showing 'HEADLINE' instead of the text. If i add the translateprovider to the big app.config parameters etc, it says this : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations' of undefined". Any idea?